# Browserify cannot find module \insert-module-globals\node_modules\is-buffer\index.js

Tags: npm, browserify

I'm trying to build reactjs application with `browserify`, but is not working for some reasons:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/browserify js/app.js > build/bundle.js
Error: Cannot find module '../c:\Projects\MyApp\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\insert-module-globals\node_modules\is-buffer\index.js' from 'c:\Projects\MyApp\node_modules\request\node_modules\combined-stream\lib'
    at c:\Projects\MyApp\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:55:21
    at load (c:\Projects\MyApp\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:69:43)
    at onex (c:\Projects\MyApp\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:92:31)
    at c:\Projects\MyApp\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

My enviroment:

```
OS: Windows 7 x64 
GNU bash, version 3.1.20(4)-release (i686-pc-msys)
nodejs: v0.12.7 
npm: v2.11.3
```

All required packages are installed:

```
$ npm list --depth=0
myapp@0.0.1 c:\Projects\MyApp
├── bootstrap@3.3.5
├── browserify@11.2.0
├── classnames@2.2.0
├── envify@3.4.0
├── flux@2.1.1
├── object-assign@4.0.1
├── react@0.14.0
├── react-dom@0.14.0
├── react-router@1.0.0-rc3
├── reactify@1.1.1
├── request@2.65.0
├── uglify-js@2.5.0
└── watchify@3.4.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've faced with the same issue after installing some libraries. I don't know the reason but after i uninstalled the global browserify and used local library for browserifying, the problem has been resolved. When i use global one, i get the same error again. Waiting for the answer???

Comment: I tried to install browserify module as global or local, but the problem was not solved. Here is my unresolved issue https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1408. A workaround to that problem might be to simply use the browser-request module instead request. Browserify works well with browser-request module